# solana-test-validator doesn't run

Tags: blockchain, solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli

On mac 11.5.2
trying to run solana-test-validator doesn't work and throws next error in terminal

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZNSt3__115basic_stringbufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE7seekoffExNS_8ios_base7seekdirEj
  Referenced from: /Users/andreyfrolov/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/solana-test-validator (which was built for Mac OS X 12.0)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
 in /Users/andreyfrolov/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/solana-test-validator
[1]    94110 abort      solana-test-validator
```

I tried to install open ssl based on suggestions, but it doesn't help

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Figuring out the problem. To fix such problem you need to follow next steps

install llvm

```
brew install llvm
```

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libc++.1.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libc++.1.dylib
```

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

After that jump into directory and run

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources

sudo ln -sf libJPEG.dylib /usr/local/lib/libJPEG.dylib

sudo ln -sf libPng.dylib /usr/local/lib/libPng.dylib

sudo ln -sf libTIFF.dylib /usr/local/lib/libTIFF.dylib

sudo ln -sf libGIF.dylib /usr/local/lib/libGIF.dylib
```

Comment: Did not work. solana-test-validator still gives me the same original error you saw, dyld symbol not found (though I'm on Catalina fwiw). Seems like libcxx might be the issue... https://github.com/darlinghq/darling/issues/1188

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue is that the version of solana cli is built for MacOS 12+.

You can try to install a lower version built for MacOS 11.

[Github Release Page](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases)

[Installation method by downloading prebuilt binaries](https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/install#macos)

However, I do not recommend using older versions because there is a risk that they might be broken or have security holes.